# coercing to Unicode: need string or bufferl, xml.etree._ElementTree found

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I' am new to python, I get the following error.

```
$ python testrun.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrun.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, lxml.etree._ElementTree found
```

With this code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('testregression_config.xml')

for elem in tree.findall('.//xmpp'):
    #assert elem.attrib['name'] == 'test02'
    elem.attrib['name'] == 'test03'

for elem in tree.findall('.//xmpp-config'):
    #assert elem.text == 'QA'
    elem.text = 'Prod'

with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:
    file_handle.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf8'))

<config>
  <logging/>
  <test-mode>false</test-mode>
  <test name="test02">
    <mail/>
    <test-system>0</test-system>
    <system id="0" name="suite1" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="1" name="suite2" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="2" name="suite3" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="3" name="suite4" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
    <system id="4" name="suite5" type="regression">
      <temp-config>Prod</temp-config>
      <rpm>0.5</rpm>
      <cycles>3</cycles>
    </system>
  </test>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:
```

you are passing lxml.etree._ElementTree Object as the file name. You probably missed a quote and intended

```
with open('tree', 'w') as file_handle:
```

The Error Msg and the Traceback is self explanatory

**Error Location**: `with open(tree, 'w') as file_handle:` so it has something to do with the `open` statement

**Error Message**: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, lxml.etree._ElementTree found`

So it seems we are passing `lxml.etree._ElementTree` instead of a string to `open`. And off course we are doing it, we are passing `tree` which is not a string but `tree = etree.parse('testregression_config.xml')`, as per the second statement in your file

Comment: @DigitalDyn: Check your quote position. Its before the opening parenthesis.